# MySQL 7pm to 7am - Realtime data based on time frame

Tags: mysql

I have relatively basic knowledge on MySQL and manage to figure out most things using google however, I cannot find what I’m looking for and, I suspect it is because I’m not typing the right words into google!

I have query that when ran, I only want it to show the data relating to the current “shift”.

Day shift    >= 07:00 and < 19:00

Night shift   >= 19:00 and < 07:00

This information is being used in a bit of a visual and refreshes regularly. This is the desired behaviour...

When >= 19:00 the data will reset back to 0 and only tickets that come in from that time until 7am the following morning will show. when >= 07:00 it needs to reset back to zero again and only show data for the day shift.

So far, I have come up with this but it is not doing what I need it to.

```
Where `startDateTime` >= IF(((CURTIME() >= '07:00:00')
                AND (CURTIME() < '19:00:00')),
            CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 07:00:00'),
            CONCAT((CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY),
                    ' 19:00:00')))
```

Comment: what is the datatype for startDateTime? also provide sample data and expected result and what do you mean with _is not doing what I need it to_

Comment: the datatype is timestamp in following format. "2022-03-29 07:00:00"
i cannot provide the sample data due to the sensitivity. the data is live information which is written to the table being queried

Comment: (Edit) @3KD3 - You don't have to post real data (or even every column in the table).  Just create a small example with the columns *relevant* to the question, (using dummy values if needed).  In this case, you probably don't need anything more than the date column, and there's nothing sensitive about dates. Here's a starter example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=23513fa1e9987a463ce02a52306884f7

Comment: ok thanks, i will get the dummy data as soon as i can

Comment: Thank you both for attempting to help, i managed to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to figure out where I was going wrong. hopefully this will help someone else.

the where statement above was working ok if the time was from midnight to 7am and from 7am to 7pm but, not if the time was after 19:00 the same day, it was pulling back data from 19:00 the day prior.

I needed a nested IF to use the current date if between 7pm and midnight.

StartDateTime it a timestamp "2022-03-29 07:00:00"

```
Where `startDateTime` >= 
            if(
                ((curtime() >= '07:00:00') and (curtime() < '19:00:00')), 
                    concat(curdate(), ' 07:00:00'),
                    if(
                        ((curtime() >= '19:00:00') and (curtime() <= '23:59:59')),
                            concat(curdate(), ' 19:00:00'),            
                            concat((curdate() - interval 1 day), ' 19:00:00'))
            )
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your final code. A few suggestions 1) Nested `if's` can be hard to read. You might consider using CASE instead.  The net effect is the same, but everything is on the same level. 2) Strictly speaking a time range check isn't necessary.  You could do the same by testing CurrentHour >= 19, CurrentHour >= 7, Else previous day...  3) It's a good practice to explicitly cast strings to the correct data type 4) Consider using a @ variable to increase the readability of the query Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=16bbeaaf341a2271a558ac5b92d52132